# Passing URL param into input value in VUE.js

Tags: vue.js

**I want to pass an URL parameter into the value of the input:**

```
<input id="para" type=text v-model="recipient">
```

I have a URL with the param `www.website.com?para=test` , how can I inject that param on page loaded into the input?

I have done it with Jquery before, but I don't know how to achieve this in VUE. Here is the Jquery code that works:

```
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
            function getURLParameter(e) {
              return decodeURI((new RegExp(e + "=(.+?)(&|$)").exec(location.search) || [, ""])[1]);
            }

            if (getURLParameter("Para") === "") {
              console.log("No URL param value found.");
            } else {
                console.log(getURLParameter("Para"));
              $("#para").value = getURLParameter("Para");
            }
        });
        </script>
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Are you using Vue Router?

Comment: Hi Phil, no, I'm not using Router

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse the query string using [`URLSearchParams()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) and then assign the value to your `recipient` data property

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <input id="para" type="text" v-model="recipient">
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({ recipient: "" }),
  created () {
    const params = new URLSearchParams(location.search)
    this.recipient = params.get("para")
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hi there Phil, the problem is the input is on a non-vue view, so it's outside the <template></template>

Comment: Doesn't sound like your question has anything to do with Vue

Comment: Hi Phil, I had already defined recipient so it was giving me error. This works like a charm! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

In your created method, you could assign the v-model value to the returned value of the function call. You would first have to create the getURLParameter function in your methods and then call it in the created method. So this way,

```
created(){
 this.recipient = this.getURLParameter("Para")
}
```